# Как сделать анимацию при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите как плавно остановить картинки камней когда они доходят до красного блока? один камень должен останавливаеться сверху красного блока, а второй снизу. Спасибо

```css
.about__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  position: relative;
}
.about__block {
  min-height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.about__stone-1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.about__stone-1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.about__stone-2 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.about__stone-2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div data-watch class="page__about">
  <div class="about__container">
    <div class="about__stone-1 _inset">
      <img src="https://dongradus.ru/upload/iblock/3a9/3a981e4f5cc55a548b933dc58223111c.jpg" alt>
    </div>
    <div class="about__block"></div>
    <div class="about__stone-2 _inset">
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [position: sticky](https://doka.guide/css/position-sticky/)

```css
.about__block {
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 700px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.about__stone-1, .about__stone-2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.about__block-1 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.about__block-2 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="about__block-1">
      <img class="about__stone-1" src="https://dongradus.ru/upload/iblock/3a9/3a981e4f5cc55a548b933dc58223111c.jpg" alt>
    </div>
    <div class="about__block"></div>
    <div class="about__block-2">
      <img class="about__stone-2" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt>
    </div>
 <body>
```